# PostgreSQL , колонка не существует

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

На мой запрос добавить данные в базу данных:

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT 
                  INTO UsersDATA (chat_id, morning_time, night_time) 
                  VALUES ('{}', {}, {})""".format(chat_id, morning_time, night_time))
```

Я получаю сообщение об ошибке :

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "chat_id, morning_time, 
night_time" of relation "usersdata" does not exist
```

В чем моя ошибка ?

Comment: Возможно вы опечатались в именах колонок. Или в имени таблицы. Или подключились не к той БД. Или в таблице вовсе нет таких колонок. Приведите в вопросе схему вашей таблицы

Comment: Да, похоже вы правы, спасибо)